# How to return HTML in React

Tags: html, reactjs

When developing my project, I look at others for an example. When I looking at Instagram website. I see the class name of html is change when user is login. May I know how to achieve that actually? As what I know, react only live in one of the div in html structure.

```
// This code will render a component in the html root.
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// But how to serve a whole new html file in react
```

How to serve a **whole new html file** in react? Is it violate the concept of react?

Comment: I think you should be more specif as whether you are trying to achieve with codes of what you have tried and what kind of errors you are facing

Comment: I want to achieve change class name of html or return a completely new html in the website. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? show codes. Also React.DOM render is not the way to go here.
You have to change the App Component and put some conditional clauses.

Comment: You wanna serve a new index.html? You can't do that with react as to say, you would have to change it in your server side code that serves those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and Document body are outside the React realm of DOM handling. So you can use good old `querySelector` for setting the class names.

```
function LoginPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('html').classList.add('login-page');
  }, []);
  return (
    // stuff
  );
}
```

A handy package is the React ecosystem for these is [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <html className="loginPage" {...anyOtherStuff} />
      <body {...attributesOnBody} />
    </Helmet>
  );
}
```

If you would like to add nodes that are adjacent to the root node in the body or React provides you with a solution called [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) that can render anywhere.

For the abiity to change `index.html` itself, you would not be building yourself a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) anymore which seems to be case to use React.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a class to your html input to retrieve it. 
Here is an exemple :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class X extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>TEXT HERE</h2>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<X/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

React works in a way that attaches itself to some DOM element. In your case, you are attaching it to some element with `id` of `root`.

**TLDR**;
Your index.html will contain the code of your application inside the element with `root` id during the runtime in the browser. You can see it by inspecting it using browser developer tools.

Your `<App />` is the root of your application and if you use `dev tools` of your browser and you inspect the DOM tree you will see components in there. They are just dynamically attached by `React (ReactDOM)` and React is in the control of when and how things are rendered.

If your components look something like:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <h1 className="title">Hello!</h1>;
}
```

In `Dev tools` your DOM structure will looks something like this:

```
<div id="root">
  <h1 class="title">Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

Here you can see that you have element with `root` id that you attached your `<App />` before and you can see the content of `<App />`, `<h1 class="title" />` together with classes.

That is also how Instagram works and most of the single-page applications or SPAs in short.

There is also a possibility to render [static version of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181349/what-is-a-static-site-generator).